# Impossible Postgres loop

Tags: postgresql, loops

I have this Postgres loop :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn insertIds() RETURNS int4 AS '
    DECLARE r RECORD;

    BEGIN
        FOR r IN SELECT id_client FROM client WHERE id_isigeo_util =153 LOOP
               INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),(SELECT max(id_livrable) FROM livrable),0,r.id_client,0,now(),0,now(),now());
        END LOOP;
    return 1;
    END;
    ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT insertIds() as output;
```

And it gives me this error :

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "temps_production_id_seq"
LINE 6: ...    INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_prod...
                                                             ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "temps_production_id_seq"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 228
```

I want to copy each of the ids contained into the select into one row of temps_production, with the serial at first position but it says error, it doesnt seem to understand nextval(), but i need it because it is a serial

EDIT : Concerning the (SELECT max(id_livrable) FROM livrable), i know it is not good because of concurrence problems that might occurs, but I've tried to get the RETURNED variable from this previous SQL insert, and it gives me an error :

```
 INSERT INTO livrable VALUES (nextval('id_livrable_fid_seq'::regclass),'',now(),now(),'',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(SELECT max(id_passation)+1 FROM passation),0) RETURNING id_livrable;
```

This is how my loop looks, after that( Please notice id_livrable who is supposed to be a variable coming from the previous sql insert...)  :

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn insertIds() RETURNS int4 
        AS 
        $body$ --<< start of the "dollar quoting"
        DECLARE r RECORD;

        BEGIN
            FOR r IN SELECT id_client FROM client WHERE id_isigeo_util =153 LOOP
               INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),id_livrable,r.id_client,0,0,now(),0,now(),now());
            END LOOP;
        return 1;
        END;
        $body$ --< end of the "dollar quoting"
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;

        SELECT insertIds() as output;
```

And the error :

```
    ERROR:  column "id_livrable" does not exist
LINE 1: ...UES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),id_livrabl...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is a column named "id_livrable" in table "temps_production", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),id_livrable,r.id_client,0,0,now(),0,now(),now())
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insertids() line 6 at SQL statement
********** Erreur **********
```

I've tried this :

```
    DECLARE myid livrable.id_livrable%TYPE;
INSERT INTO livrable VALUES (nextval('id_livrable_fid_seq'::regclass),'',now(),now(),'',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(SELECT max(id_passation)+1 FROM passation),0) RETURNING id_livrable INTO myid;
```

but error :

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "livrable"
LINE 2: DECLARE myid livrable.id_livrable%TYPE;
                     ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "livrable"
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 15
```

**EDIT 2 :** It is finnaly working like that , case closed thank you ( I will do the code you provideed too):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn insertIds() RETURNS int4 
        AS 
        $body$ --<< start of the "dollar quoting"
        DECLARE r RECORD;
        DECLARE myid livrable.id_livrable%TYPE;
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO livrable VALUES (nextval('id_livrable_fid_seq'::regclass),'',now(),now(),'',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(SELECT max(id_passation)+1 FROM passation),0) RETURNING id_livrable INTO myid;
            FOR r IN SELECT id_client FROM client WHERE id_isigeo_util =153 LOOP
               INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),myid,r.id_client,0,0,now(),0,now(),now());
            END LOOP;
        return 1;
        END;
        $body$ --< end of the "dollar quoting"
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;

        SELECT insertIds() as output;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you i'm trying, but the insert was working alone like this

Comment: Why are you using `select max()` if you are using a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem are the nested single quotes.

To avoid problems with that use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn insertIds() RETURNS int4 
AS 
$body$ --<< start of the "dollar quoting"
DECLARE r RECORD;

BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT id_client FROM client WHERE id_isigeo_util =153 LOOP
           INSERT INTO temps_production VALUES (nextval('temps_production_id_seq'::regclass),(SELECT max(id_livrable)+1 FROM livrable),0,r.id_client,0,now(),0,now(),now());
    END LOOP;
return 1;
END;
$body$ --< end of the "dollar quoting"
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT insertIds() as output;
```

With that the embedded single quotes that you need for the name of sequence don't require escaping.

---

But you don't need a loop for this. A simple `insert .. select` will perform much better. And you should run the expensive (and probably incorrect)  `select max()` only once:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTIOn insertIds() RETURNS int4 
AS 
$body$
DECLARE 
  l_count bigint;

BEGIN
   -- ATTENTION: 
   -- this will not work correctly with concurrent transactions on the livrable table!
   SELECT max(id_livrable)+1 
      into l_count
   FROM livrable;

   INSERT INTO temps_production 
   select nextval('temps_production_id_seq'),
          l_count,
          0, 
          c.id_client,
          0,
          now(),
          0,
          now(),
          now()
    FROM client c
    WHERE id_isigeo_util = 153;

    return 1;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT insertIds() as output;
```

---

It's also good coding style to explicitly state the column in the `insert` statement:

```
insert into temps_production (id, ....) 
select ...
```

Comment: @nick: please see my edit. Your function is needlessly complex

Comment: Ok, yes i agree, selectmax() is not right, but I'm trying to get the RETURNING variable named 'id_livrable' from a previous SQL INSERT, but the loop then doesn't accept or recognize it.

Comment: The insert can potentially return multiple IDs, but your function is defined as `returns int` so you can't return more then one value from that function

Comment: I've edited my message, do you use RETURNING variables sometimes ? I can't inject my RETURNING variable into my loop from my previous INSERT query thank you